# Are there distributions for skewness and kurtosis? Similarly to mean (normal) and variance (chi-squared)

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, skewness, chi-squared-distribution, kurtosis

My question is really straightforward.

The distribution of the sample means approaches a normal distribution (CLT).

The distribution of the sample variance approaches a chi-square distribution (Cochran's theorem).

This is for the first and second moments of a distribution. Do we have something similar for the third and fourth moments?

Comment: Cochran's theorem states that under normal population, the sampling distribution of sample variance is chi-squared, not asymptotic. The sample variance also asymptotically follows a normal distribution, which you can derive using the delta method, and so does the sample standard deviation.

Comment: You should be able to derive similar results for higher moments, but the assumptions will need to include finite higher moments.

Comment: *Raw* moments are means of powers of a random variable and therefore the CLT applies directly to them, to the extent those powers satisfy the conditions of the CLT (such as having finite variances).  This is true even of raw second moments and variances: the standardized distribution of the sample variance of any nondegenerate random variable with finite *fourth* moment is asymptotically standard Normal. In this sense higher moments present no new phenomena.